# Formatting JSON in a textarea

Tags: javascript, json, internet-explorer-9, textarea

I have a page where I want to let the user edit an application - stored in a JSON. It looks like this:

```
{"address":{"House_Number":505,
"Street_Direction":"",
"Street_Name":"Claremont",
"Street_Type":"Street",
"Apt":"15L",
"Burough":"Brooklyn",
"State":"NY",
"Zip":"10451",
"Phone":"718-777-7777"},
"casehead":0,
"adults":[{"Last_Name":"Foo",
"First_Name":"A",
"Sex":"M",
"Date_Of_Birth":"01011980"}],
"children":[]}
```

I am setting this using

```
var pattern = ",", re = new RegExp(pattern, "g");
  casedetails.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(apps[0]).replace(re , ",&#10;");
```

The problem is after I make changes, the first time I run this, the textarea doesn't show the newlines - even though they are there! (If I copy/paste they show up). If I refresh it shows the newlines.

Can anyone help me figure out how to get JSON on new lines without having to refresh? I am using IE 9

Thanks!

-Tom

Comment: Check out the [documentation of `JSON.stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify).

Comment: can't reproduce -> **http://jsfiddle.net/heL4kkj7/** ?

Comment: @adeneo sadly no. In the fiddle my entries are still not on new lines

Answer (score 9, accepted):

this should be pretty simple...
take a look if this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/w870d3tc/3/) fit your needs

```
   var yourObject = {"address":{"House_Number":505,
    "Street_Direction":"",
    "Street_Name":"Claremont",
    "Street_Type":"Street",
    "Apt":"15L",
    "Burough":"Brooklyn",
    "State":"NY",
    "Zip":"10451",
    "Phone":"718-777-7777"},
    "casehead":0,
    "adults":[{"Last_Name":"Foo",
    "First_Name":"A",
    "Sex":"M",
    "Date_Of_Birth":"01011980"}],
    "children":[]};

var textedJson = JSON.stringify(yourObject,undefined, 2);
document.getElementById("json-area").value = textedJson

;
```

P.S. i've used jQuery just to speed-up the example but the function on which you should focus is `JSON.stringify`

Comment: i removed jquery from the example...try now

Comment: Sorry still not working. Now I'm seeing the '&#10;' characters visible after every comma

Comment: Sorry but the purpose of the regex was to insert new lines ?? In this case is totally useless, the stringify function does it automatically...try to check the fiddle